# Hide ActionBar on ListView scroll contained in a Fragment within a ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to hide the ActionBar on ListView scroll.

The official documentation suggests we use this pattern to do so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I can't, however, use this pattern since my "Scrollable view" is a ListView inside a Fragment that is rendered inside the ViewPager. I use the following code in my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.x.y.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                style="@style/AppTabLayout"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried putting the ViewPager inside the AppBarLayout, and the Toolbar and TabLayout in a CollapsibleToolbarLayout. However, if I do that, the ViewPager layout isn't even shown and the ActionBar is permanently hidden.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

`CoordinatorLayout` doesn't work with listview. So either replace the listview with a recyclerview (which i would highly recommend) or put your listview inside a `NestedScrollView`. The xml code you posted is ok. If any of these is not working then post your fragment's xml code and hit me up again